# How to Return 2 json Objects from Python which i can catch in Jquery(Front end)

Tags: jquery, json, django, python-2.7

My Python File-->

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json as simplejson
import random

def Detail(request):
    res1 = "[{\"index\":\"1\",\"status\":\"0\",\"name\":\"xyz1\"},{\"index\":\"2\",\"status\":\"1\",\"name\":\"xyz2\"},{\"index\":\"3\",\"status\":\"3\",\"name\":\"xyz3\"}]";
    res2 = "[{\"index\":\"1\",\"address\":\"1\",\"email\":\"a@a.com\",\"area\":\"xyz\"},{\"index\":\"2\",\"address\":\"2\",\"email\":\"a@a.com\",\"area\":\"xyz\"}]"
    res3 = "{\"office\":\"xyz\",\"dept\":\"xyz\",\"location\":\"xyz\",\"building\":\"xyz\",\"floor\":\"xyz\",\"emp\":\"xyz\"}"
    result = simplejson.dumps({'lsd':res1,'detail':res2,'office': res3})
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(result), content_type = "application/json")
```

Where as my `JQuery` file is:

```
function onCall(item) 
{
  alert(item.lsd.name);
  alert(item.detail.index);
  alert(item.office.dept);
}
```

So My Question is how to construct this line:
I am not able to alert it in front end.
It says"item.lsd" not found as I want to clubbing the json string from back end and sending it as response

```
result = simplejson.dumps({'lsd':res1,'detail':res2,'office': res3})
```

in `python` so that i can alert it in `Frontend` and i dont want to change this line

```
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(result), content_type = "application/json")
```

Comment: your question doesn't make sense (_"how to construct this line in `python` so that i can alert it in `Frontend` and i dont want to change this line"_) ...not sure what you mean. but you should only encode to JSON __once__ ...here you are taking 3 already-JSON strings `res1` `res2` `res3` then adding them to a dict and encoding as JSON again (to give `result`), then encoding `result` as JSON a third time... ending up with a big mess no doubt

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what the problem is.

But one obvious issue is that the various `res` variables are already JSON strings. So if you add them to a dict and dump the whole thing to JSON, those values will be double-escaped.

Don't do that. Define those variables as the basic types:

```
res1 = [{"index": "1", "status": "0", "name": "xyz1"},
        {"index": "2", "status": "1", "name": "xyz2"},
        {"index": "3", "status": "3", "name": "xyz3"}]
```

and so on.

Also, you then take your `result` dict and dump it to JSON, then you dump it *again* when you return the response. Don't do that: just do it once.

Comment: I am not able to alert it in the front end

Comment: Because you're encoding it three times. Don't do that, as I said.